# when to use byte stream or character stream to read/write text

Tags: java, character, byte

I am a java newbie.

I understand that one must use character stream to read/write characters and a byte stream to read/write bytes.

However, I can also use a byte stream to read/write characters.

I also understand that character streams are preferred while using an internationally used application.

1. Could you give some advice on when to use a character stream versus a byte stream while reading/writing 'text' data?
2. can text in word/excel/pdf document be simply read using character stream?
3. When and how would I know when to use character encoding like UTF-8/Western/ISO while reading text data created externally? (i am sorry this is vague question...but please help)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Multiple questions should be asked separately](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).

Answer (score 3):

1. Use Readers and Writers when you know the data is text. Otherwise use streams.
2. No. You don't know that the data is text so see (1).

Answer (score 2):

Generally if you just want to read such a file and send it somewhere else or guardrlo always best to use for bytes.

To file for treating bytes is advisable to use buffer, an example would be the "BufferedOutputStream".

On the other hand if you need to use to read the content text is always advisable to know that "encode" you will get. The most versatile option is "BufferedReader", with this option you will use the "encode" default having java.

Finally comment that you can not read files Work, Excel, etc ... directly because they formatted, you need tools that allow you to read, I use "Apache POI".

regards,

Comment: @Manu....just to make sure I got this right..any text file that is received from an external source or to be sent to an external source could be written/read using byte stream? But what about the issue of losing characters while reading or writing characters as byte (for characters that need 2 bytes)

Comment: Do not quite understand your question, if you read the file in bytes and send it in bytes, the file is sent exactly the same, if you read in characters and send it in characters (Readers> Writers) no loss as long as the "encode "is the file was created, regards,

Comment: Actually what I understood from your comment was that one 'must' use a byte stream just because a text file (character text) is received from an external source or to be sent to an external source.

Comment: Yes, if not you have to process data is the most recommended, but you have to send a string or read it sometime you have to know your "encode" and then it's recommended Readers or Writers